# Custom dashboard for many hosts from Zabbix

Tags: php, frontend, dashboard, zabbix

I want to create frontend dashboard which will display only status of UPS (green or red). I create page which use Zabbix widget system status. So i have page with static data. How i can make it dynamic  and receive new data from Zabbix?

here the part of php code:

```
     <tbody>
                   <tr>
                      <td><a href="tr_status.php
filter_set=1&amp;groupid=10&amp;hostid=0&amp;show_triggers=1">L1</a></td>
                     <td class="normal-bg">0</td>
                      <td class="normal-bg">0</td>
                      <td class="normal-bg">0</td>
                      <td class="normal-bg">0</td>

                   </tr>
```

As you see all values of cells are static - 0 but it should be flexible. If trigger up - 1, if down - 0.

Comment: This is way too broad, basically asking for somebody to code it for you, while choosing the solution as well. Don't think it is answerable in the stackoverflow concept.

Comment: Ok. I thought it will be not so hard. Anyway thank you for answer

Comment: Why do you create a page if Zabbix already have dashboard, maps and screen? Just create 2 images in Paint, put a text in image (let's say UPS1) add green as background color in one and red in the another. Upload those images to zabbix. Create a map in Zabbix, add   the images as Trigger. Default image status will be the green one, problem status will be the red.

Comment: Nice idea. I didnt think about it.